# using std Namespace in R instead of RCPP

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm learning C++ with plans to implement it almost entirely in conjunction with R. I get a little tired of appending the namespace "std" to tons of code though. Is there a way to use namespace std for most of the code and switch the namespace to Rcpp just for the compile and sourcing?

Below is a C++ "Hello World" function with namespace Rcpp. This is a trivial example, but lays out the problem. "string" is not a class in Rcpp, so I have to append std:: to it. Again, I know this is a trivial example, but I just want to know if it is possible.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::string hello(std::string x) {
  return x;
}


/*** R
hello("Hello World")
*/
```

Output works as expected, but I'd love if I could make the code look something like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

using namespace std;

string hello(string x) {
  return x;
}


using namespace Rcpp;

/*** R
hello("Hello World")
  */
```

This way, as the bulk of the code expands, I don't have to append std to everything.

Comment: You misunderstand how the compiler works.  `using namespace foo;`  is global to the compilation unit (_i.e._ file).  You cannot have it for half a file.

Comment: I would advise against `using std;` for more than  small examples. Same for `using Rcpp;`.  As an alternative you can use focused `using namespace::function;`.

Comment: @Ralf is spot on.  While we are showing _how_ to do it, it worth remember that for larger projects you _probably should not_ do it as the chance for clashes among the identifiers is real.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. To clarify, for a large project you wouldn't declare a namespace at all?

Comment: From the various syntax examples at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace I would not use "5) using-directive" (at least for large namespaces). All other uses, including "6) using-declaration" are fine from my point of view.